# top command's CPU usage calculation

Tags: linux, cpu, gnu-coreutils, top-command

I am trying to use GNU coreutil top's formula for calculating CPU usages in percentage.
But top is using some half_total, to calculate the percentage, which is adding 0.5 to the percentage.

In utils.c of top's [source](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/unixtop/top-3.8beta1.tar.gz?modtime=1210117842&big_mirror=0), the following line  (at 3.8 beta1, it is in line number: 459): -

*out++ = (int)((*diffs++ * 1000 + half_total) / total_change);

This translates to :
( (*diffs++  *  1000) / total_change ) + 1/2
So, it always gives a number, which is: "10 times the percentage, plus 0.5". So if the percentage is x, it will return 10x+0.5.

Can anyone explain how is this average calculated? or at least some pointer where I can get the help?

PS:
Why can't we just use `(*diffs++/total_change) * 100` to get the required percentage?

Top's source code is located at: -
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/unixtop/top-3.8beta1.tar.gz?modtime=1210117842&big_mirror=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way to do **rounding** for integer values, because the division discards the fractional part.

When you add half the divisor this is equivalent to a floating point division and rounding up if the fractional part is 0.5 or greater.

Comment: but what about the "10x" part?

Comment: Because the value is in tenths of a percent.