# Computation of Cpu percentage by a single process in unix by the "top" command

Tags: c++, c, unix, solaris

I would like to know how does the "top" command compute the cpu percentage used by any process.

I have tried reading the "psinfo" binary file in the /proc directory , but it didnt help in finding the result.

Please provide any information how it can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not duplicate but related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552976/top-commands-cpu-usage-calculation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `top` command computes the CPU usage using the data in the [proc file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs).  The actual file containing the CPU usage data can vary from one platform to another.  For example, in Linux it is found in [`/proc/<pid>/stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) and for Solaris it is found in [`/proc/<pid>/psinfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1473/proc-4.html#scrolltoc).  The CPU usage  is calculated as the difference in cumulative CPU time for a process divided by the amount of time measured between updates.

---

For Linux, you can inspect the [**procps**](http://procps.sourceforge.net) source which includes `ps`, `top`, and other process tool from [*http://procps.sourceforge.net*](http://procps.sourceforge.net).  The [readproc.c](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/proc/readproc.c?view=markup) file in particular contains the functionality for retrieving the data.

---

For Solaris, you can inspect the [**libproc**](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+observability/libproc) source from [*https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/lib/libproc*](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/lib/libproc).  The [prog_get_info.c](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/lib/libproc/common/proc_get_info.c) file contains the functionality for retrieving the data and storing it in a [`psinfo_t`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/sys/procfs.h) struct.

---

For Linux, Solaris, and others, you can inspect the [**Unix Top**](http://www.unixtop.org) source from [*http://sourceforge.net/projects/unixtop*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unixtop).  The platform-specific source files within the `machine` directory contain the functionality for retrieving the data.

---

**Update**

Another option (Solaris only) for retrieving CPU time for a process may be passing to the [`PIOCPSINFO`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/fs/proc/prioctl.c#l2526) or [`PIOCSTATUS`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/fs/proc/prioctl.c#l855) option to the [`ioctl()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1463/ioctl-2.html#scrolltoc) system call.  The [`PIOCPSINFO`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/fs/proc/prioctl.c#l2526) option returns miscellaneous process information in a [`prpsinfo_t`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/intel/sys/old_procfs.h#l247) struct.  The [`PIOCSTATUS`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/fs/proc/prioctl.c#l855) option returns status information for the process in a [`prstatus_t`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/intel/sys/old_procfs.h#l172) struct.

Adapted from example code at [*http://getthegood.com/TechNotes/Papers/ProcStatistics.html*](http://getthegood.com/TechNotes/Papers/ProcStatistics.html):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd;
    prpsinfo_t info;
    prstatus_t status;
    char procbuf[50];

    sprintf(procbuf, "/proc/%d", getpid());
    fd = open(procbuf, O_RDONLY);

    ioctl(fd, PIOCPSINFO, &info);
    printf("Process user+sys time = %ld sec %ld nsec\n" 
           "Reaped children user+sys time = %ld sec %ld nsec\n",
           info.pr_time.tv_sec, info.pr_time.tv_nsec,
           info.pr_ctime.tv_sec, info.pr_ctime.tv_nsec);

    ioctl(fd, PIOCSTATUS, &status);
    printf("Process user+sys time = %ld sec %ld nsec\n"
           "Sum of children's user+sys time = %ld sec %ld nsec\n",
           status.pr_utime.tv_sec+status.pr_stime.tv_sec,  
           status.pr_utime.tv_nsec+status.pr_stime.tv_nsec,  
           status.pr_cutime.tv_sec+status.pr_cstime.tv_sec,
           status.pr_cutime.tv_nsec+status.pr_cstime.tv_nsec);

    close(fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

<sub>**Note: This code is untested and omits error checking for simplicity.**</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am checking all the options given by you , though the psinfo didnt work out for me earlier also.