# Finding user's resource utilization in ubuntu linux

Tags: c, linux, statistics

I want to know, how can we find user's process statistics about resource utilization( like CPU, Memory) using c program and without using any user command tool. Currently I am running ubuntu 10.10. 
Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450961/computation-of-cpu-percentage-by-a-single-process-in-unix-by-the-top-command) and  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux) may be of some assistance to you.

Comment: @mdec They are process specific whereas I need it for user specific. I think, I have to iterate through all process and calculating user's statistics by UID of a process. But if there is any more efficient way then it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way these days is to parse the information in the `/proc` virtual filesystem `procfs`.  It contains textual information on nearly all aspects of the system, including detailed per-process statistics.  The information is structured, and is intended for ease of parsing and programmatic access.  (This is how tools such as `ps` work.)

For example, to query the I/O metrics of a given process, you would read the file under `/proc/<pid>/io`.  This contains a series of `name: value` pairs, like so:

```
rchar: 14823550
wchar: 138670414
syscr: 11549
syscw: 3013
read_bytes: 483328
write_bytes: 8192
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

For detailed information, see:

- ["The /proc Filesystem"](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) - kernel reference documentation